# Convert cyclic directed graph to tree (Arborescence)

Tags: data-structures, graph, tree, cycle, directed-graph

I have this requirement, where I want to convert a directed cyclic graph into a tree given 1 vertex, which will be the root.

From my research I found out that I need to create an [Arborescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory)), which HAS to be acyclic, in order to convert it into a tree. Is it impossible to create a directed rooted tree from a cyclic directed graph?

Here's an example of the vertexes and its edges.

[image: Directed Cyclic Graph]

Comment: The generated tree will have an infinite depth, but can be lazily produced at runtime.